# MasterCard API can't find file

Tags: java, mastercard

I am trying yo use Transaction Notifications API. In their website they're asking to get the .pem and .p12 files to the Java project resources. I can not find the .pem and do not understand what I'm missing.

https://developer.mastercard.com/transaction-notifications/documentation/tutorials/java-tutorial/

Comment: "Create a new project and add the Transaction Notifications API to your project.

   **A zip file will be downloaded automatically with your keys.**
" Did you do that?

Comment: yes sure, i found just the .p12